# How can I catch Access-Control errors?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm working with an API that sometimes doesn't set the right Access-Control headers for CORS requests.

How can I inform the user that something went wrong when an Access-Control error occurs?  I don't even need to know what error occurred, just that the XHR request failed.

Wrapping the request in a try/catch block doesn't seem to work in WebKit browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest attaching an `onerror` handler to the `XMLHttpRequest` instance.

Comment: Are you sure? Here is a [sample code on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XjdVh/). It calls `http://www.example.com` which does not feature any CORS headers. The error alert message is shown. Could you specify what headers does the buggy API actually send?

Comment: Ah, you're right... I was trying to attach to a jqXHR object, which of course isn't the actual XHR. Looks like I'll have to implement my own ajax method, or dive into $.ajax. Also worth noting: www.example.com wasn't triggering an Access-Control error, but if you change it to www.google.com (for example), you will still get an error in the console (as well as an `onerror` event).  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery? You can attach global error handlers with `$.ajaxError()`.

Comment: `$.ajaxError()` doesn't get called unfortunately.